# Nameservers at freehostingcloud

Tags: nameserver

How can I change the nameservers at freehostingcloud? I got a message:

You need to change the nameservers for your domain exampledomain.net. The nameservers should be ns1.freehostingcloud.com and ns2.freehostingcloud.com.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name servers at the registrar you used to register your domain name.

So wherever you registered your domain name, log in to their control panel using the account you registered with, and then find where you can specify your name servers. Then just put in the name servers your host provided.

It may take a few hours for the DNS records to propagate before you can access your site via the domain name.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately I was unable to find the place where to change it.

Comment: @Jaska: Where did you register your domain name? You may want to try contacting them. This is the main service that domain registrars provide, and it's probably the most common action performed by registrar users. So the user interface should make it pretty easy to change your name servers. Though if you want to avoid this hassle in the future, you may just want to buy your domain from your web host. Most paid hosting companies also give you a free domain, so it's not a bad deal, and everything will be set up for you automatically.

Comment: I registered it at http://www.freehostingcloud.com and when I asked they wrote me that I have to change the address. Well, I asked them again where can I find the place to change them.

Comment: @Jaska: That's where you registered your _domain name_ from? If that's the case, then they should have set it up for you already. The only reason a web host would ask you to manually change your DNS records is if you registered your domain with a different company--otherwise they're completely incompetent.

Comment: I think they haven't set it to me. Probably they assumed that I already had an address.

Comment: @Jaska: if you never paid a ~$9/year registration fee, then you probably haven't registered a domain yet--unless you're using their paid hosting plan and it comes with a domain (I don't know if it does or not).

Comment: @Jaska, This type of support really gets up my nose. It doesn't take more than a couple of minutes to explain to someone what and how to do something or why. If hosting companies just spent a little more time being user friendly they would cut down the number of calls in the long run. I know the service they offer is free but they should still provide some level of decent support... If you give us the domain name we will be able to tell you who it is registered with and how to contact them.